# Vertically Centering Inline Content Using line-height

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying to vertically center some text besides two image links. I've done this dozens of times before but for some reason it isn't working right now.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/KRWNw/

```
<style type="text/css">
#social-icons {
    height:32px;
    line-height:32px;
}​
</style>

<div id="social-icons">
    Connect:
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://mydomain.com/rodi/images/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://mydomain.com/rodi/images/youtube.png" width="32" height="32" />
    </a>
 </div>​
```

If I take the images out the text aligns perfectly, but with the images in it won't align.

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img{
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

use this css.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mangalauwu/KRWNw/8/)

Answer (score 3):

One thing that is missing is the `vertical-align: middle;` that will only get you half way. The other issue is your inline images. If you `float` the images left or right, it will align correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/tU4x7/

images are left of the content in this example, but you can float the text as well if you wrap it in a span. There are other solutions to achieve the same thing though.

Comment: Thank you, this works but floating isn't as flexible for me as the `vertical-align:middle;` solution. Is there any reason I should use this method instead?

Comment: @DannyCooper no both methods work. If you can avoid using a float, that is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

```
img{vertical-align:middle;}
```

But I wouldn't use it like that, since the icons isn't a real part of your page or content. Consider to use the img as an background image instead.
There is a great [CSS framework](http://zocial.smcllns.com/) for this